# not able to convert bigdecimal to string in java

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

Here is the java code

```
usageType = (String) c.getSrcValue("USAGETYPE");
```

c is a arraylist.
I populate it with this field from DB.
 `"USAGETYPE" NUMBER(*,0)`,

I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to String
```

Can you please help me out

Answer (score 10):

Well, you cannot convert an object to a string by casting. Not in Java, in any case.

Try

```
usageType = c.getSrcValue("USAGETYPE").toString();
```

That is, if you actually need it as a string, which smells a little dubious in the first place. Usually the only place where numbers are needed as strings is the UI and you've got appropriate other places to do that conversion, normally (e.g. CellRenderers in Swing).

Answer (score 6):

Simply write

```
usageType = c.getSrcValue("USAGETYPE").toString();
```

or

```
usageType = ""+c.getSrcValue("USAGETYPE");
```

Comment: @trashgod : thanks for formatting. I will take care of putting in formatted code henceforth :)